distance of a point from the lines that are contained in a list
I am making a python animation for a project in which, I am taking a star shaped boundary in which there are two balls which are moving inside that star. If the balls collide to other balls, a new ball is formed. The star boundary is working as wall of room , that if ball touches it , gets bounced off (according to the angles of reflections) the problem I am facing is how would i define the bouncing function , I have made the star using line segments and all those line segments are stored in a list. I want to define it like, if the distance between the any of the line segments from the list and the ball is less than the ball's radius then it gets bounced off. The problem is, if I define that function then it is taking complete equation of the line and the  straight lines that are the borders of the star (if extended) also passes through inside the star and the ball is getting  bounced off from those invisible lines. How can I define that function that it works only for line segments not for the extended lines. I did this animation for a circle , it is easy to handle it with a circle because there is only one line "the circumference of that circle" to define functions for. Here is a working code for circle. You don't need to go through whole code , it is just for the idea for how I am doing it.
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set up the window
width, height = 600, 600
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Bouncing Balls Inside a Circle")

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (255, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)]

# Circle parameters
circle_center = (width // 2, height // 2)
circle_radius = 200
circle_thickness = 3

# Ball parameters
ball_radius = 10
balls = []

# Function to create a new ball with a random color
def create_ball():
    angle = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
    distance = random.uniform(0, circle_radius - ball_radius)
    x = circle_center[0] + distance * math.cos(angle)
    y = circle_center[1] + distance * math.sin(angle)
    speed = [random.choice([-.25, .25]), random.choice([-.25, .25])]  # Random initial speed
    color = random.choice(colors)
    return {"pos": [x, y], "speed": speed, "color": color}

# Function to check collision between balls
def check_collision(ball1, ball2):
    dist = math.sqrt((ball1["pos"][0] - ball2["pos"][0]) ** 2 + (ball1["pos"][1] - ball2["pos"][1]) ** 2)
    return dist <= 2 * ball_radius

# Function to handle collision and ball bouncing
def handle_collision(ball1, ball2):
    dx = ball2["pos"][0] - ball1["pos"][0]
    dy = ball2["pos"][1] - ball1["pos"][1]
    distance = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
    overlap = 2 * ball_radius - distance
    normal_x = dx / distance
    normal_y = dy / distance
    correction = [overlap * normal_x, overlap * normal_y]
    ball1["pos"][0] -= correction[0]
    ball1["pos"][1] -= correction[1]
    ball2["pos"][0] += correction[0]
    ball2["pos"][1] += correction[1]

    # Calculate reflection angles
    dot_product1 = ball1["speed"][0] * normal_x + ball1["speed"][1] * normal_y
    dot_product2 = ball2["speed"][0] * normal_x + ball2["speed"][1] * normal_y

    reflect_x1 = ball1["speed"][0] - 2 * dot_product1 * normal_x
    reflect_y1 = ball1["speed"][1] - 2 * dot_product1 * normal_y
    reflect_x2 = ball2["speed"][0] - 2 * dot_product2 * normal_x
    reflect_y2 = ball2["speed"][1] - 2 * dot_product2 * normal_y

    ball1["speed"] = [reflect_x1, reflect_y1]
    ball2["speed"] = [reflect_x2, reflect_y2]

# Function to add a new ball to the circle
def add_new_ball():
    if len(balls) > 0:
        balls.append(create_ball())

# Add two initial balls
balls.append(create_ball())
balls.append(create_ball())

# Main loop
while True:
    window.fill(BLACK)

    # Check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Update ball positions
    for ball in balls:
        ball["pos"][0] += ball["speed"][0]
        ball["pos"][1] += ball["speed"][1]

    # Check if any two balls collide
    for i in range(len(balls)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(balls)):
            if check_collision(balls[i], balls[j]):
                handle_collision(balls[i], balls[j])
                add_new_ball()  # Add a new ball if collision occurs

    # Check if the balls hit the walls of the circle
    for ball in balls:
        distance_to_center = math.sqrt((ball["pos"][0] - circle_center[0]) ** 2 + (ball["pos"][1] - circle_center[1]) ** 2)
        if distance_to_center + ball_radius >= circle_radius:
            # Calculate reflection angle
            dx, dy = ball["speed"]
            normal_x = ball["pos"][0] - circle_center[0]
            normal_y = ball["pos"][1] - circle_center[1]
            mag_normal = math.sqrt(normal_x ** 2 + normal_y ** 2)
            normal_x /= mag_normal
            normal_y /= mag_normal
            dot_product = dx * normal_x + dy * normal_y
            reflect_x = dx - 2 * dot_product * normal_x
            reflect_y = dy - 2 * dot_product * normal_y
            ball["speed"][0] = reflect_x
            ball["speed"][1] = reflect_y

    # Draw the circle
    pygame.draw.circle(window, WHITE, circle_center, circle_radius, circle_thickness)

    # Draw the balls
    for ball in balls:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, ball["color"], (int(ball["pos"][0]), int(ball["pos"][1])), ball_radius)

    pygame.display.flip()


I just want to replace the circular boundary with a star shaped boundary. Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

The concept that will help you here is finding the projection of the point onto the line segment.  This is the spot that a normal projection from the line/segment would intersect the point.
Find this point and then test to see if it is within the max/min of the either the x or y (pick one) and at 1-radius distance, then it is touching and bounce it.
Make a couple helper functions and test them, then just call the functions in your loop.

I won't rewrite your program for you, but the solution can be found with:

Define a star. You mentioned a "list" which is great, your list will look something along the lines of star_points = [ (x, y) ] where x,y are the coordinates for each node of the star. Then you simply call it like pnt1 = star_points[z].

Since a circle is not a star, you will need to rework your collision and bounce functions.



It isn't clear how this answers the fundamental question of colliding only with the line segment

Couldn't you just add a "star" sprite on top of your functionality circle? Like, treating the circle as backend and the star as frontend.

then how to define equation for star and function to check collision , because that function needs to calculate distance from the border, how would i define that distance function
